# Decompress an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, compression

I need to decompress an array and I am not sure where to start.

Here is the input of the function

```
def main():
    # Test case for Decompress function
    B = [6, 2, 7, 1, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 0]
    A = Decompress(B)
    print(A)
```

I want this to come out

```
A = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 9, 0, 0]
```

If you can't see the pattern, `B[1]` is how many times `B[2]` shows up in `A[]`, and then `B[3]` is how many times `B[4]` shows up in `A[]`, and so on.

How do I write a function for this?

Comment: What does "decompress" mean in this context? I think you mean to start at B[0] and there are not 6 "2"s in A...

Comment: Did you make any attempt so solve it? If yes, please share it with us.

Comment: I tried but it's not even close to what I want.

Comment: by "decompress", I mean that I'm given a "compressed" array and by using some sort of algorithm I need to "decompress" it, basically I want to somehow "decode" the first array and make it into the second but using the method I explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def unencodeRLE(i):
    i = list(i) #Copies the list to a new list, so the original one is not changed.
    r = []

    while i:
        count = i.pop(0)
        n = i.pop(0)
        r+= [n for _ in xrange(count)]
    return r
```

Comment: what does pop do? I am new to python

Comment: removes the last element from the list and returns it, or, with a parameter, returns a specific element.

Comment: and why do you have an underscore after the for?

Comment: so it could potentially be anything?

Comment: could you edit this with some line comments for me, that would be really helpful, it works I'm just not sure what going on in the while loop

Comment: IMHO, very ineffective. Even pop seems to be a strange choice, but I may understand it. But why list comprehension when it is enough to use  [n] * count which is simpler and faster?

Comment: And it is a VERY bad practice to create a function that silently modifies the list.

Comment: @Ellioh I went for clarity not for "do it in one line", your solution is better, yes, but i think  more difficult to understand

Comment: No, I have nothing against several lines. And even effectiveness may not be the most important thing. The main problem is that the function modifies its parameter (i). That's a hidden effect the caller may not be ready to.

Answer (score 3):

Compact version with `zip()` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable([v] * c for c, v in zip(*([iter(B)]*2))))
```

Demo:

```
>>> B = [6, 2, 7, 1, 3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 0]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([v] * c for c, v in zip(*([iter(B)]*2))))
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 9, 0, 0]
```

Breaking this down:

- `zip(*([iter(B)]*2)))` pairs counts with values:

  ```
  >>> zip(*([iter(B)]*2))
  [(6, 2), (7, 1), (3, 5), (1, 9), (2, 0)]
  ```

  It is a fairly standard Python trick to get pairs out of a input iterable.
- `([v] * c for c, v in zip(*([iter(B)]*2)))` is a generator expression that takes the counts and values and produces lists with the value repeated count times:

  ```
  >>> next([v] * c for c, v in zip(*([iter(B)]*2)))
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
  ```
- `chain.from_iterable` takes the various lists produced by the generator expression and lets you iterate over them as if they were one long list.
- `list()` turns it all back to a list.

Comment: Heh.  Mine was `list(chain.from_iterable([y]*x for x,y in zip(*[iter(B)]*2)))`; one obvious way, I guess.  (I prefer your variable names, though.)  [edit: +1 now that it's all explainy!]

Answer (score 0):

One more one-liner:

```
def decompress(vl):
    return sum([vl[i] * [vl[i+1]] for i in xrange(0, len(vl), 2)], [])
```

1. A list comprehension extracts and unpacks pairs (`xrange(0, len(vl), 2)` iterates through start indices of pairs, `vl[i]` is a number of repetitions, `vl[i+1]` is what to repeat).
2. `sum()` joins the results together (`[]` is the initial value the unpacked lists are sequentially added to).

Answer (score 0):

A slightly faster solution (with Python 2.7.3):

```
A=list(chain.from_iterable( [ B[i]*[B[i+1]] for i in xrange(0,len(B),2) ] ) )

>>> timeit.Timer(
        setup='B=[6,2,7,1,3,5,1,9,2,0];from itertools import chain',
        stmt='A=list(chain.from_iterable( [ B[i]*[B[i+1]] for i in xrange(0,len(B),2) ] ) )').timeit(100000)
0.22841787338256836
```

Comparing with:

```
>>> timeit.Timer(
        setup='B=[6,2,7,1,3,5,1,9,2,0];from itertools import chain',
        stmt='A=list(chain.from_iterable([v] * c for c, v in zip(*([iter(B)]*2))))').timeit(100000)
0.31104111671447754
```